# Cлово "счастье"

Tags: этимология, лексика

А что обозначает слово "счастье"?

Answer (score 2):

Интерес к этимологии слова "счастье", да и к смыслу его (я для себя разделяю эти понятия), проявился у меня не так давно и вылился в небольшое эссе, которое не публиковалось по простой причине: появляются новые размышления и новый материал, иногда вступающий в противоречия с уже изложенным.

В силу этого мне уже пару лет приходится дополнять и перекраивать материал.

Иногда охватывает оторопь из-за невозможности объять необъятное, и вероятность завершения этой работы представляется асимптотически стремящейся к нулю.

Неисследованность этого расхожего понятия сопоставима с космосом и с самим Homo Sapiens - сколько людей, столько мнений (причём спорных)!

Не пытаясь втянуть коллег в дискуссию на эту тему (хотя было бы тоже интересно!..) разрешаю себе привести одно из толкований этого состояния из А. и Б. Стругацких, почитаемых мной весьма.

"Счастье - это кратковременное ощущение радости бытия, возникающее от сознания хорошо выполненного замысла" (Журнал "Смена" №1 1966 г.).

Answer (score 1):

**Счаґстье**, Ближайшая этимология: Укр. Щаґстя ср. р.; цслав. СъчЯСтьнъ "причастный", др.-чеш. «‰e№stie, чеш. «te№stiґ "счастье", «t'аStnyґ "счастливый", слвц. «t'аStiе, «t'аStnyґ, польск. szcze§sґcie. Дальнейшая этимология: Праслав. *sъ‰e§stь^je объясняют из* sъ - : др.-инд. su - "**хороший**" + *‰e§stь "**часть**", т. е. "**хороший удел**" (Бодуэн де Куртенэ, Stud. Brµcknerowi 220 и сл.; Гуйер, LF 46, 188 и сл.; Френкель, Мeґl. Реdеrsеn 444; Махек, ZfslPh 7, 378). По мнению Бернекера (1, 155), Счаґстье -- первонач. "доля, совместное участие" (: Съ). Эта этимология несомненна для позднецслав. СъчЯСтьнъ "причастный".(http://fasmerbook.com/p687.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Простите, не очень понятно что такое "обозначать" по отношению к какому-либо слову.
Обозначать слово может что-то, если используется как какой-то знак, несет какой-то скрытый смысл, становится символом... Это нормальный авторский прием (было целое течение  "символистов" в поэзии), но без контекста сказать, что именно слово *обозначает* в конкретном тексте, невозможно.

Ну а если речь идет о самом значении слова, то тут сложностей нет. Можно довериться любому словарю.

Вот БТС Кузнецова.

СЧАСТЬЕ, -я; ср.
~1.
Состояние высшей удовлетворённости жизнью, чувство глубокого довольства и радости, испытываемое кем-л.; внешнее проявление этого чувства. Семейное с. Желаю счастья. С. народа. Стремление к счастью. С. созидания. С. общения друг с другом. Человек создан для счастья. Быть любимым - великое с. Огромное с. С. написано, светится на лице у кого-л. Глаза озарены счастьем. Ощущение счастья. Слёзы, улыбка счастья. Найти своё с. в детях, в работе. Какое с. видеть вас! /
В учтивых оборотах. Сочту за с. говорить с вами. Имел с. встречаться со знаменитостью. Не имею счастья его знать.

~2.
Успех, удача. С. в игре, в любви. Военное с. Во всём с. кому-л. С. изменило, улыбнулось кому-л. Верить в своё с. Найти подкову - к счастью. Попытать, попробовать счастья
(предпринять что-л., рассчитывая на успех). Дать, сделать на с.
(чтобы был успех, удача). Слепое с. (счастливый случай). Дай Бог кому-л. счастья
(пожелание успеха, удачи). * Не было бы счастья, да несчастье помогло (Посл.).

~3. Разг.
Участь, доля, судьба. Эта девушка - твоё с. Найти своё с. * Всякому своё с. (Погов.). Человек - кузнец своего счастья (Посл.).

~4. в функц. сказ.
(с придат. дополнит., с инф.).
Хорошо, удачно. С., у кого есть дети. Какое с., что мы вместе! Твоё с., что не было заморозка (разг.;
повезло тебе). < К счастью; на счастье; по счастью, в зн. вводн. словосоч.
Выражает удовлетворение по поводу чего-л. К счастью, дождь кончился. На (наше) счастье, была хорошая погода. По счастью, никто не встретился. Счастьице, -а; ср. Уменьш.

Выбирайте )))

Comment: Быть "причастным" к определённому событию или чувству, при котором человек получает полноту и есть счастье.
Первое определение точное и правильное.